Error: SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered. using java 7,ojdbc8.jar,tomcat 7 and oracle 19c
java code:
public void addAttachment(ChildrenValue childrenValue, String childrenId, Connection con) throws SQLException, IOException {
        int i = 0;

        // SQL queries for insertion and retrieval of BLOB data
        String sqlNewRow = "INSERT INTO PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT (QUOT_ID, CHILD_ID, QUOT_NAME, QUOT_FILETITLE, QUOT_SIZE, QUOT_FILENAME, QUOT_DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?, ?, EMPTY_BLOB(), ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        String sqlLockRow = "SELECT QUOT_NAME FROM PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT WHERE QUOT_ID = ? AND CHILD_ID = ? FOR UPDATE";
        String sqlSetBlob = "UPDATE PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT SET QUOT_NAME = ? WHERE QUOT_ID = ? AND CHILD_ID = ?";
        
        PreparedStatement initAttachmentPrepdStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement newAttachmentPrepdStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement insertAttachmentPrepdStmt = null;
        
        try {
            initAttachmentPrepdStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlNewRow);
            newAttachmentPrepdStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlLockRow);
            insertAttachmentPrepdStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlSetBlob);
            
            Vector addedAttachment = childrenValue.getAddedAttachment();
            Iterator iteratorQ = addedAttachment.iterator();
            
            LOGGER.info("Starting to insert attachment data for children...");
            
            while (iteratorQ.hasNext()) {
                ChildrenActionForm quotData = (ChildrenActionForm) iteratorQ.next();
                i++;
                
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setLong(1, i);
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(childrenId));
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setString(3, quotData.getFileTitle());
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setString(4, quotData.getSize());
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setString(5, quotData.getFileName());
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.setString(6, quotData.getContentType());
                initAttachmentPrepdStmt.executeUpdate();
                
                newAttachmentPrepdStmt.setLong(1, i);
                newAttachmentPrepdStmt.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(childrenId));
                ResultSet rs = newAttachmentPrepdStmt.executeQuery();
                
                if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                    // The connection is still open
                    LOGGER.info("connection is ok");
                } else {
                    // The connection has been closed
                    LOGGER.info("connection closed");
                }
                
                if (rs != null) {
                    // The cursor is still open
                    LOGGER.info("cursor is open");
                } else {
                    // The cursor has been closed
                    LOGGER.info("cursor closed");
                }
                
                if (rs.next()) {
                    Blob dbBlob = rs.getBlob("QUOT_NAME");
//                    byte[] byteAccess = dbBlob.getBytes(1, (int) dbBlob.length());
                    byte[] byteAccess = quotData.getByteData();
                    LOGGER.info("Byte data size: " + byteAccess.length);
                    InputStream inputStream = dbBlob.getBinaryStream();
                    LOGGER.info("binary stream.....: " + dbBlob.getBinaryStream());
                    // Process the InputStream
                    // For example, save it to a file
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sqlSetBlob); //"PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT"
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                con.close();
            LOGGER.info("Transaction committed successfully.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.info("SQL Exception: " + e);
            con.rollback();
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("Unexpected error: " + e);
            con.rollback();
            throw new SQLException("Unexpected error during attachment insertion.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (initAttachmentPrepdStmt != null) initAttachmentPrepdStmt.close();
                if (newAttachmentPrepdStmt != null) newAttachmentPrepdStmt.close();
                if (insertAttachmentPrepdStmt != null) insertAttachmentPrepdStmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.info("Error closing resources: " + e);
            }
        }
    }


tomcat log :

12/12/2024 12:35:11.334 - [ess.personnelinfo.resource.ChildrenDataAccess.addAttachment] - [INFO] - connection is ok
12/12/2024 12:35:11.334 - [ess.personnelinfo.resource.ChildrenDataAccess.addAttachment] - [INFO] - cursor is open
12/12/2024 12:35:11.334 - [ess.personnelinfo.resource.ChildrenDataAccess.addAttachment] - [INFO] - Byte data size: 40085
12/12/2024 12:35:16.807 - [ess.personnelinfo.resource.ChildrenDataAccess.addAttachment] - [INFO] - SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered

        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:168)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:543)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1405)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:822)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:1446)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1371)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1900)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:363)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:407)
        at oracle.sql.LobPlsqlUtil.plsql_getChunkSize(LobPlsqlUtil.java:1202)
        at oracle.sql.LobPlsqlUtil.plsql_getChunkSize(LobPlsqlUtil.java:121)
        at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBAccess.getLobChunkSize(DBAccess.java:955)
        at oracle.sql.LobDBAccessImpl.getChunkSize(LobDBAccessImpl.java:111)
        at oracle.sql.BLOB.getChunkSize(BLOB.java:228)
        at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBufferSize(BLOB.java:242)
        at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:124)
        at ess.personnelinfo.resource.ChildrenDataAccess.addAttachment(ChildrenDataAccess.java:1586)
        at ess.personnelinfo.business.PersonnelInfoBusiness.submitChildren(PersonnelInfoBusiness.java:1668)
        at ess.personnelinfo.presentation.PersonnelInfoBusinessDelegate.submitChildren(PersonnelInfoBusinessDelegate.java:770)
        at ess.personnelinfo.presentation.ChildrenAction.doApplyChildrenResult(ChildrenAction.java:573)
        at ess.personnelinfo.presentation.ChildrenActionBase.applyChildrenResult(ChildrenActionBase.java:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.perform(DispatchAction.java:236)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionPerform(ActionServlet.java:1787)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1586)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:510)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at ess.filter.AppFilter.doFilter(AppFilter.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:119)
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2531)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2520)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

SQL Database:
CREATE TABLE "ESSQAS"."PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT"
  (
    "CHILD_ID"       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    "QUOT_ID"        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    "QUOT_FILENAME"  VARCHAR2(400 BYTE),
    "QUOT_FILETITLE" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE),
    "QUOT_SIZE"      VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "QUOT_NAME" BLOB,
    "QUOT_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
  )
  SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
  )
  TABLESPACE "USERS" LOB
  (
    "QUOT_NAME"
  )
  STORE AS SECUREFILE
  (
    TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 NOCACHE LOGGING NOCOMPRESS KEEP_DUPLICATES STORAGE(INITIAL 106496 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  ) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ESSQAS"."SYS_IL0001127038C00006$$" ON "ESSQAS"."PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT"
  (
    PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) ;

PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT table:



COLUMN_NAME
DATA_TYPE
NULLABLE
DATA_DEFAULT
COLUMN_ID
COMMENTS




CHILD_ID
VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
YES
(null)
1
(null)


QUOT_ID
VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
YES
(null)
2
(null)


QUOT_FILENAME
VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
YES
(null)
3
(null)


QUOT_FILETITTLE
VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
YES
(null)
4
(null)


QUOT_SIZE
VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
YES
(null)
5
(null)


QUOT_NAME
BLOB
YES
(null)
6
(null)


QUOT_DESCRIPTION
VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
YES
(null)
7
(null)



Example PA_CHILDREN_ATTACHMENT data:




CHILD_ID
QUOT_ID
QUOT_FILENAME
QUOT_SIZE
QUOT_NAME
QUOT_DESCRIPTION




1
1
1
test
11920
(BLOB)
application/word


2
2
1
test
40926
(BLOB)
application/pdf




You cannot use ojdbc8 with Java 7 as it's compiled for Java 8 (and if you're really still using Java 7 - and Tomcat 7 for that matter - in this day and age, you really have big problems).

before i upgrade database oracle 19c from oracle 12c with the same driver and java version, it worked fine. nothing errors appeared.

The point is that ojdbc8 cannot possibly work with Java 7 (the classes would not load because of an UnsupportedClassVersionError), and it would indicate that you're actually using a different driver (e.g. ojdbc7 or ojdbc6) that is also lying around on your classpath, or you're actually using Java 8 or higher.
